# Sequence of futures in Scala are empty

Tags: scala

This code:

```
object TestFutures2 extends App {

  def double (i:Int) = Future { i * 2 }

  var futures = Seq[Future[Int]]()

   for ( x <- 1 to 5) {
          futures = futures :+ double(x)
   }                

   println("futures: "+futures)

   Future.sequence(futures).map {
     result => println("result: "+result)
   }

  Thread.sleep(10000)
}
```

prints:

```
futures: List(List(), List(), List(), List(), List())
result: List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
```

What's the meaning of the `futures` variable? why is it a list of empty lists? Shouldn't it be a `Seq[Future[Int]]` as declared?

Comment: Is your Future `scala.concurrent.Future`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually seems to work fine for me.

It displays

```
[DEBUG 08:06:45] futures: List(Future(<not completed>), Future(<not completed>), Future(<not completed>), Future(<not completed>), Future(<not completed>))
[DEBUG 08:06:45] result: List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
```

Running inside Scalatest with a custom logger that just does

```
System.out.print(s"[DEBUG ${customTimerMethod}] $message \n")
```

Printing out a Seq converts it into a List, if you try to simply println("someSeq: " + Seq()) it'll still be a list. This is most likely because Java doesn't have a Seq so it converts it to it's closest ancestral type.

---

As @CyrilleCorpe pointed out in the comments, incomplete `Future`s are not displayed in the REPL and show up as empty `List`s

Comment: why `Future(<not completed>)` is printed as `List()` ?

Comment: these are the imports: `import scala.concurrent._` and  
`import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`

Comment: In REPL, uncompleted `Future`s are printed out as `List()`.

Comment: I'm using version 2.11

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet Never noticed that before, can confirm :)